# GNU Make documentation: contradiction in ifdef?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

The following is the documentation for the ifdef conditional in GNU Make. What is this suppose to be telling me?

```
conditional-directive
text-if-true
else
text-if-false
endif
```

The ifdef form takes the name of a variable as its argument, not a reference to a variable. **The value of that variable has a non-empty value, the text-if-true is effective;** otherwise, the text-if-false, if any, is effective. Variables that have never been defined have an empty value. The text variable-name is expanded, so it could be a variable or function that expands to the name of a variable.

Note that **ifdef only tests whether a variable has a value. It does not expand the variable to see if that value is nonempty.** Consequently, tests using ifdef return true for all definitions except those likefoo =. To test for an empty value, use ifeq ($(foo),).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `ifdef` form takes the *name* of a variable as its argument, not a reference to a variable. The value of that variable has a non-empty value, the *text-if-true* is effective; otherwise, the *text-if-false*, if any, is effective. Variables that have never been defined have an empty value.

Lets say we've a variable `foo`, then it having a value assigned is good enough for `ifdef` to deem it `true`, it doesn't care about `foo`'s actual value. Some may consider `0` or an empty string to be falsey, but not `ifdef`.

```
foo = 0      # or even ''
ifdef foo    # true, bar will be set to 1
   bar = 1
else
   bar = 0
endif
```

> Note that `ifdef` only tests whether a variable has a value. It does not expand the variable to see if that value is nonempty.

So, when it already has a variable, no further expansions are made (like above).

> The text *variable-name* is expanded, so it could be a variable or function that expands to the name of a variable.

However, when we pass a reference to a variable or a function, then expansion is done. The example given in the [same document](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) clarifies this:

```
bar = true
foo = bar
ifdef $(foo)
frobozz = yes
endif
```

> The variable reference `$(foo)` is expanded, yielding `bar`, which is considered to be the name of a variable. The variable `bar` is not expanded, but its value is examined to determine if it is non-empty.

The confusion is due to this line:

> Note that `ifdef` only tests whether a variable has a value. It does not expand the variable to see if that value is nonempty.

This would've been better:

> Note that `ifdef` only tests whether a variable has a value. It does not *test* the variable to see if that value is nonempty.

Comment: I don't think it would be better. Variable evaluation is consistently called variable expansion in make manuals, as far as I've seen.

Comment: Perhaps, but IMHO, _test_ as used in the previous statement is more unambiguous, clearly conveys the intent, even if one isn't used to reading `make` document.

Answer (score 1):

The docs explanation also makes me confused.

I try to explain it by the following steps (not sure if it's always correct):

1. If the right side of equal sign is empty, then consider the variable as undefined, otherwise, defined.
2. If the right side of `ifdef` is a variable name, then I look up the name to see if it is defined.
3. If the right side of `ifdef` is  a variable reference, I evaluate its value and see its result as the actual variable name that `ifdef` wants to test, then I look up the name to see if it is defined.

e.g.

```
bar =        # the right side of equal sign is empty (nothing), it's undefined
foo1 = bar # the right side of equal sign is not empty(bar), it's defined
abc1 = foo1 # the right side of equal sign is not empty(foo1), it's defined
foo2 = $(abc1) # the right side of equal sign is not empty($(abc1)), it's defined

all:
ifdef foo1   # variable name is foo1, defined
    echo "1. foo1 is defined"
endif

ifdef abc1 # variable name is abc1, defined
    echo "2. abc1 is defined"
endif

ifdef foo2  # variable name is foo2, defined
    echo "3. foo2 is defined"
endif

ifdef $(foo1)   # variable name is bar, undefined
    echo "4. $(foo1) is defined"
endif

ifdef $(abc1) # variable name is foo1, defined
    echo "5. $(abc1) is defined"
endif

ifdef $(foo2) # variable name is foo1, defined
    echo "6. $(foo2) is defined"
endif
```

result:

```
echo "1. foo1 is defined"
1. foo1 is defined
echo "2. abc1 is defined"
2. abc1 is defined
echo "3. foo2 is defined"
3. foo2 is defined
echo "5. foo1  is defined"
5. foo1  is defined
echo "6. foo1   is defined"
6. foo1   is defined
```